# Android TV - Software Manual - Structure of Each Screen (UX look)

Tags: data-request, releasing-data

I have to map all Android TV screens that End User has in Android Tv. Is there a Structure Map of Android TV ? Something like manual ?

I am looking for Manual/Specification for Android TV. In this manual : - Structure Map - Each TV Option shown - Options Map - EPG, Smart TV, Options with all options - Module Map - HDMI, USB, WiFi

Any vendor ? LG , Philips , Sony ?